# Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORACLE

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I try to connect to Oracle SQL, and everything is normal, Console notification connect success, no error in console:

```bash
2023-04-27 17:28:50 INFO  [main           ] m.service.promotion.PromotionApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-04-27 17:28:50 INFO  [main           ] y.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-27 17:28:50 INFO  [main           ] y.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 31ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-27 17:28:50 INFO  [main           ] amework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope : BeanFactory id=d5b7dc3c-7593-38a4-b712-ceb098e944ec
2023-04-27 17:28:50 INFO  [main           ] boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9004 (http)
2023-04-27 17:28:50 INFO  [main           ] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-04-27 17:28:50 INFO  [main           ] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
2023-04-27 17:28:51 INFO  [main           ] e.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-04-27 17:28:51 INFO  [main           ] ntext.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 938 ms
2023-04-27 17:28:51 INFO  [main           ] rg.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-27 17:28:51 INFO  [main           ] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2023-04-27 17:28:51 INFO  [main           ] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-04-27 17:28:51 INFO  [main           ] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-27 17:28:51 INFO  [main           ] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-04-27 17:28:51 INFO  [main           ] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:32 WARN  [main           ] t.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl : HHH000069: Duplicate generator name SEQ_STORE
2023-04-27 17:29:34 INFO  [main           ] a.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-04-27 17:29:34 INFO  [main           ] a.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-27 17:29:34 WARN  [main           ] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-04-27 17:29:34 INFO  [main           ] duling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

But when I run API using a code, this code get Entity Customer from Database:

```java
Customer customer = commonMgr.getEntityById(Customer.class, customerId);
```

I have an error:

```bash
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:747) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

This is a Customer Class:

```java
package com.service.promotion.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.service.promotion.enumtype.ActiveType;
import com.service.promotion.enumtype.IsAttribute;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_STORE", sequenceName = "CUSTOMER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_STORE")
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Long id;
    
}
```

I think My App was connected with Oracle database, but I was error below. Help me solve it! Thank you!

Comment: I think your Entity model trying to connect to different database. Can you share with application.properties? And database connection

Comment: @Yeras_QazaQ I update Customer Class I define in Project to Post.

Comment: Thank you! What about your package scan? Which part of your project makes scan for finding entiry? Also what do you for using request, JPARepository or CrudRepository?

Answer (score 0):

First of all did you try to connect database with user credentials in the code to check whether the table is actually exist or not using Database client like Oracle SQL Developer?

This error happens due to one of below reasons.

- User you used to connect to the Database does not have access to the schema which table reside
- The table simply does not created yet
- There is a something wrong in connecting entity to Database, possible small name error or something.

Please check whether one of these conditions apply to your code.

Comment: I connect DB with DataGrip success, table is exists in DB!

Comment: @trannguyenhan Did you check the schema?

Comment: I config in my code:
```java
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DMS_DB_URL}
    username: #${DMS_DB_USERNAME}
    password: #${DMS_DB_PASSWORD}
```

No config schema in my code, Where can I set it in my project?

Comment: I trying add schema: ${SCHEMA}, so it error!

Answer (score 0):

You could verify if you have access to this table and/or if the table `CUSTOMER` exists by trying this SQL command:

```
select owner as schema_name,
       table_name
from sys.all_tables
where table_name like 'CUSTOMER';
```

More information can be found in the following link: https://dataedo.com/kb/query/oracle/find-tables-which-names-start-with-specific-prefix

Comment: Yes, table already exists